# onComplete() never gets called after successful downloading the pdf (Rxjava) but works when used AsyncTask

Tags: java, android, pdf, android-asynctask, rx-java

I am trying to download a pdf file from the url using onNext() of Rxjava2. After downloading and storing the file in the folder, I have written the code logic in the oncomplete() to open up the pdfview through intents to show up the pdf to the user. But the onComplete() never gets called. Have used breakpoints as well to check but the compiler doesnt never executes the onComplete().

MainActivity:

```
        home_quarantine_guidelines.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {

                 observable = Observable.just
                        ("https://www.w3.org/WAI/ER/tests/xhtml/testfiles/resources/pdf/dummy.pdf");

                observable.subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
                        .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
                        .subscribe(new DisposableObserver<String>() {
                            @Override
                            public void onNext(String s) {
                                //customProgressDialog.show();

                                String extStorageDirectory = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString();
                                File folder = new File(extStorageDirectory, "Intelehealth_COVID_PDF");
                                folder.mkdir();

                                File pdfFile = new File(folder, "dummy.pdf");

                                try{
                                    pdfFile.createNewFile();
                                }catch (IOException e){
                                    e.printStackTrace();
                                }

                                FileDownloader.downloadFile(s, pdfFile);

                            }

                            @Override
                            public void onError(Throwable e) {

                            }

                            @Override
                            public void onComplete() {
                                customProgressDialog.dismiss();

                                File pdfFile = new File
                                        (Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()
                                                + "/Intelehealth_COVID_PDF/" + "dummy.pdf");

                    Uri path = FileProvider.getUriForFile
                            (context, context.getApplicationContext().getPackageName()
                                    + ".provider", pdfFile);
                    Intent pdfIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
                    pdfIntent.setDataAndType(path, "application/pdf");
                    pdfIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);
                    pdfIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
                    pdfIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_WRITE_URI_PERMISSION);

                    try{
                        startActivity(pdfIntent);
                    }catch(ActivityNotFoundException e){
                        Toast.makeText(HomeActivity.this, "No Application available to view PDF", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }

                            }
                        });

//                File pdfFile_downloaded = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/Intelehealth_COVID_PDF/" + "dummy.pdf");
//
//                if(pdfFile_downloaded.exists())
//                {
//                    File pdfFile = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/Intelehealth_COVID_PDF/" + "dummy.pdf");  // -> filename = maven.pdf
//                    //Uri path = Uri.fromFile(pdfFile);
//                    Uri path = FileProvider.getUriForFile
//                            (context, context.getApplicationContext().getPackageName()
//                                    + ".provider", pdfFile);
//                    Intent pdfIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
//                    pdfIntent.setDataAndType(path, "application/pdf");
//                    pdfIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);
//                    pdfIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
//                    pdfIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_WRITE_URI_PERMISSION);
//
//                    try{
//                        startActivity(pdfIntent);
//                    }catch(ActivityNotFoundException e){
//                        Toast.makeText(HomeActivity.this, "No Application available to view PDF", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
//                    }
//                }
//                else
//                {
//                    customProgressDialog.show();
//                    new DownloadFile().execute("https://www.w3.org/WAI/ER/tests/xhtml/testfiles/resources/pdf/dummy.pdf", "dummy.pdf");
//                }




            }
        });
```

FileDownloaded.class:

```
public class FileDownloader extends FileProvider {
    private static final int  MEGABYTE = 1024 * 1024;

    public static void downloadFile(String fileUrl, File directory){
        try {

            URL url = new URL(fileUrl);
            HttpURLConnection urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection)url.openConnection();
           // urlConnection.setRequestMethod("GET");
          //  urlConnection.setDoOutput(true);
            urlConnection.connect();

            InputStream inputStream = urlConnection.getInputStream();
            FileOutputStream fileOutputStream = new FileOutputStream(directory);
            int totalSize = urlConnection.getContentLength();

            byte[] buffer = new byte[MEGABYTE];
            int bufferLength = 0;
            while((bufferLength = inputStream.read(buffer)) > 0){
                fileOutputStream.write(buffer, 0, bufferLength);
            }
            fileOutputStream.close();
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

> EDIT: When I use AsyncTask, the code executes correctly. But why does
>   it not execute/work using RxJava2 ?

Comment: Because you are running the network request on the main thread. You should be using `Single.fromCallable` and run the network request in that, not in subscribe.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. Can u show some code or example link for more info pls. Also, u mentioned that I am running the netowork request on the main thread - How did u came to know abt this? can u explain pls!

Answer (score 1):

From the hint given by @EpicPandaForce in his comment, I figured out the issue. I was using create operator of Rxjava to emit a single item. Due to which it was never reaching the onComplete(). With the given hint and referring the documentation, I realized that I have to use Single.fromCallable() as I wanted to emit a single thread.

Code:

```
  Single.fromCallable(() ->
            {
                String s = "https://www.w3.org/WAI/ER/tests/xhtml/testfiles/resources/pdf/dummy.pdf";
                String extStorageDirectory = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString();
                File folder = new File(extStorageDirectory, "Intelehealth_COVID_PDF");
                folder.mkdir();

                File pdfFile = new File(folder, "dummy.pdf");

                try{
                    pdfFile.createNewFile();

                }catch (IOException e){
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

                FileDownloader.downloadFile(s, pdfFile);


                return s;
            })
                    .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
                    .subscribe(new SingleObserver<String>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onSubscribe(Disposable d) {

                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onSuccess(String s) {
                            File pdfFile = new File
                                    (Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()
                                            + "/Intelehealth_COVID_PDF/" + "dummy.pdf");

                            Uri path = FileProvider.getUriForFile
                                    (context, context.getApplicationContext().getPackageName()
                                            + ".provider", pdfFile);
                            Intent pdfIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
                            pdfIntent.setDataAndType(path, "application/pdf");
                            pdfIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);
                            pdfIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
                            pdfIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_WRITE_URI_PERMISSION);

                            try{
                                startActivity(pdfIntent);
                            }catch(ActivityNotFoundException e){
                                Toast.makeText(HomeActivity.this, "No Application available to view PDF", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            }
                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onError(Throwable e) {

                        }
                    });
```

Comment: The main issue was that I was using Create operator for emitting a single item whereas I had to use Single.fromCallable. One has to be really very careful while using the opeartors in rxjava.